# Add and remove active class based on scope value

Tags: angularjs

Hi am not aware of angularjs that much.On my page load am defining an scope value as `true/false`  based on `location.hash`.

```
if(location.hash=='#en'){
        $scope.selectedLang=true;
    }
    else{
        $scope.selectedLang=false;
    }
```

when `selectedLang` is true I need to add active class to the `a` element in `li`. when `slectedLang` is false I need to remove active class in `a` element.

```
<li><a href="#eng" >english</a></li>
   <li><a href="#hin" >hindi</a></li>
```

By default `selectedLang` should be true.How can I get it?Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ng-class like this,

```
<li><a href="#eng" ng-class="{'active' : selectedLang}">english</a></li>
<li><a href="#hin" ng-class="{'active' : !selectedLang}">hindi</a></li>
```

If you want to have styles directly instead of classes, you need to use like this,

```
<li><a href="#eng" ng-style="{ color :  selectedLang ? 'blue' : '#ddd', background: selectedLang ? 'red' : '#fff'}">english</a></li>
<li><a href="#hin" ng-style="{ color :  selectedLang ? 'blue' : '#ddd', background: selectedLang ? 'red' : '#fff'}" >hindi</a></li>
```

And set selectedLang = true by default

```
$scope.selectedLang=true;
if(location.hash != '#en'){
    $scope.selectedLang=false;
}
```

Comment: can I add any css instead `active` class?

Comment: yes you can. For that you need to use ng-style. But prefer ng-class, it's cleaner

Answer (score 1):

you can use the ternary operator with ng-class as following

```
<a href="#eng" ng-class="selectedLang ? 'active' : ''">english</a>
```

[Reference](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)